# Android - Can I create a TextView or EditText onClick of the previous Fragment button?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

My `FragmentActivity` has 2 `Fragments`, `FragmentA` and `fragmentB`. In the `FragmentA` there have a `button`. `onClick` of the `fragmentA` `button`, I need to create a `TextView` and `EditText` in `FragmentB`. I have called a method of `FragmentB` `onCick` event of the `FragmentA` `button`. The method is as fillow:

```
public void updateFragmentB(String t) {
TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            tv.setText(t);
}
```

But it's not working.

Here is my onCreate method in FragmentB:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);

    b_received = (TextView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.b_received);
    b_received.setText("Wait For the text");
    tv = new EditText(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    String myTag = getTag();

    ((AndroidViewPagerActivity)getActivity()).setTabFragmentB(myTag);

    return myFragmentView;
}
```

My fragment_b layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="It's Fragment B" />
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/b_received"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:scaleType="center"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Fragment B` you will have to first define a Layout and then create your `TextView` and `EditView`, you will then have to add these `TextView` and EditText to those `layouts` and then add that layout to the `ContentView`.

You may accomplish this in following ways:

1. Either define your `layouts`, `TextView` and `EditText` in the xml then add that xml to your content view like this

   ```
   setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout_b);
   ```
2. Or If you have already got the Layout defined and you want programmitcally get the Layout by using the `findViewById()` method and then add your newly created `TextView` and `EditText` objects to this layout.

You cannot just simply create `TextView` or `EditText` objects and leave it for it to appear it on the `Fragment B` you will have to add them to the Layout used on the `Fragment B`.

If you need further help with the `Fragment B` then share the code of `onCreateView()` method

Now that I can see your onCreateView Method I can see 
tv = new EditText(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

I am assuming that 'tv' is a EditText reference variable and I cant't see the tv being added to your layout. So you will have to add tv to your appropriate Layout.

Or you can Add the EditText to your layout in the xml like you have added your TextView.

ok So now i can view you layout xml:

1.Add android id to your LinearLayout:

1. In your code use LinearLayout lLayout =  myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.lLayout);
   to get the LinearLayout object.
2. Now add your EditText view object to your LinearLayout object :

   lLayout.addView(tv); //if tv is the EditText object

Comment: I have added my onCreate method. Please help a bit more.

Comment: @ray when you say it is not working then are you getting any exceptions? or are the EditText and TextView are not coming up?

Comment: @ray Also I have added my response to your onCreateView method in the answer. Please share your R.layout.fragment_b xml file?

Comment: Thanks. How I can add the tv in my layout programmatically. I need to create the tv on condition.

Comment: @ray share your R.layout.fragment_b xml file

Comment: Added the fragment_b xml file

Comment: @ray I have added my response in the Answer